# How to register open generic types, closed generic types and decorate both using autofac?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am using Autofac as my IoC container. 
I have:

1. `IRepository<>`, my repository interface;
2. `DbContextRepository<>`, a generic implementation of a repository using EntityFramework's DbContext;
3. Some closed types repositories inside an assembly, say  `PersonRepository : DbContextRepository<Person>`;
4. And a `RepositoryDecorator<>`, which decorates my repositories with some standard extra behavior;

I'm using autofac to register them all like this:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(DbContextRepository<>))
            .Named("repo", typeof(IRepository<>));

builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
                typeof(RepositoryDecorator<>),
                typeof(IRepository<>),
                fromKey: "repo");            

var repositorios = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(PersonRepository));
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(repositorios).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
          .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IRepository<>))
          .Named("repo2", typeof(IRepository<>))
          .PropertiesAutowired();

builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
               typeof(RepositoryDecorator<>),
               typeof(IRepository<>),
               fromKey: "repo2");
```

What I am trying to do is:

1. to register the `DbContextRepository<>` as a generic implementation of `IRepository<>`;
2. then register the closed types repositories, so they can overload the previous registration when needed;
3. Then decorate them both so, when I ask the container to resolve a IRepository, it gives me a RepositoryDecorator with the right implementation of IRepository, being it a DbContextRepository or the closed type already registered.

When I try to resolve an `IRepository<Product>`, which has no closed type implementation, it returns correcly a Decorated DbContextRepository.

But when I try to resolve an `IRepository<Person>`, which **has** a closed type implementation, it also gives me a Decorated DbContextRepository, instead of a Decorated PersonRepository.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your issue, can you provide more code please, a concrete decorator might help?  Is RepositorioVisibilidade meant to be RepositoryDecorator?

Comment: I'll try to make some unit tests and contribute it to Autofac as an extensions, with credits to @default.kramer, something like `.AsNamedClosedTypesOf(...)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `Named("repo2", typeof(IRepository<>))` isn't doing what you think. You need to specify the type explicitly for the type that is being scanned.

```
static Type GetIRepositoryType(Type type)
{
    return type.GetInterfaces()
        .Where(i => i.IsGenericType
            && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IRepository<>))
        .Single();
}

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(this.GetType().Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(DbContextRepository<>)))
    .As(t => new Autofac.Core.KeyedService("repo2", GetIRepositoryType(t)))
    .PropertiesAutowired();
```

Comment: It worked fine. What I was looking for was something like .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IRepository<>), withName:"repo"), which doesn't exists, but is just what you did.

Comment: Great answer.  This was a tricky one as it isn't particularly discoverable from the API.

Comment: Thanks! Not discoverable indeed, the - very good, don't get me wrong - documentation only shows an example for generic decorators on top of generic registrations