# How to register all subtypes of a generic type?

Tags: inheritance, types, reflection, autofac

I'm trying to distill this (and more):

```
builder.RegisterType<ZipCodeRepository<ZipCode>>.AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<MemberRepository<Member>>.AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<CreditRepository<Credit>>.AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<DebitRepository<Debit>>.AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<StateRepository<State>>.AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<CityRepository<City>>.AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

...into something like this:

```
Type[] inheritedTypes;
Type baseType;

baseType = typeof(Repository<Entity>);

inheritedTypes = baseType.Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type =>
{
  return type.BaseType.Name == baseType.Name;
}).ToArray();

builder.RegisterTypes(inheritedTypes).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

The LINQ query works, returning all (and only) repositories that inherit from `Repository<Entity>`, but I'm still getting an Autofac resolution error:

> Cannot resolve parameter `IZipCodeRepository<ZipCode> ZipCodeRepository`

Here's where I'm attempting to resolve the repository:

```
public class GetZipCodeByCodeQueryHandler : Handler
{
  public GetZipCodeByCodeQueryHandler(string unitOfWork, IZipCodeRepository<ZipCode> zipCodeRepository) : base(unitOfWork)
  {
    _zipCodeRepository = zipCodeRepository;
  }
}
```

My goal is to automatically register these, so that I don't have to create a registration for every new entity I create in my application (I'm just getting started and already it's becoming overly tedious).

I tried a variation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8581915), which *might* address my situation (loosely if at all):

```
builder
  .RegisterAssemblyTypes(baseType.Assembly)
  .Where(type => type.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(Repository<>)))
  .As(type => GetIRepositoryType(type)).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

...but that didn't work. I tried it with both `Repository<>` and `IRepository<>`.

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16758650). No luck. Same error.

How can I automate registration of my repositories in a single expression, rather than have to maintain the ever-growing list manually?

**--BEGIN EDIT--**

What's really strange is that `t` comes out of this an empty list:

```
var t = new List<Type>();

builder
  .RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
  .Where(type =>
  {
    t.Add(type);
    return type.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(Repository<>));
  })
  .As(type => this.GetIRepositoryType(type)).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Assuming I'm reading this correctly, which I think I am, Autofac isn't attempting to evaluate any types *at all*. How does THAT figure?

**--END EDIT--**

Here's a fully reproducible example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Autofac;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] Args)
    {
        Succeeds();
        Fails();
    }

    private static void Succeeds()
    {
        IContainer container;
        ContainerBuilder builder;

        builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<ZipCodeRepository<ZipCode>>.AsImplementedInterfaces();
        container = builder.Build;
        container.Resolve<IZipCodeRepository<ZipCode>>();
    }

    private static void Fails()
    {
        Type baseType;
        Type[] allTypes;
        IContainer container;
        ContainerBuilder builder;

        baseType = typeof(Repository<Entity>);
        allTypes = baseType.Assembly.GetTypes().ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine(allTypes.Contains(typeof(ZipCodeRepository<ZipCode>)));

        builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterTypes(allTypes).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        container = builder.Build;
        container.Resolve<IZipCodeRepository<ZipCode>>();
    }
}

public interface IRepository<T> where T : Entity
{
}

public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity
{
}

public abstract class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IZipCodeRepository<T> : IRepository<ZipCode> where T : ZipCode
{
}

public class ZipCodeRepository<T> : Repository<ZipCode>, IZipCodeRepository<ZipCode> where T : ZipCode
{
}

public class ZipCode : Entity
{
}
```

Comment: You might get a better response if the language posted was C#. While it doesn't matter (could be VB, could be F#, whatever), you may be limiting yourself to who can read and mentally parse/convert to something more familiar (myself included) - it's been YEARS since I did VB and I never did figure out generics and LINQ with it).

Comment: Because you asked so nicely, I converted it ;-)

Comment: There's no resolve call here. Can you also show what you're resolving so folks might repro and be sure we're seeing the same thing you are?

Comment: It's a DI/constructor resolution. I posted the code. I'll put together a GitHub repro project tomorrow.

Comment: Instead of a whole repo, try for [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) right here. I think you're pretty much there. To repro this, it looks like someone could `container.Resolve<IZipCodeRepository<ZipCode>>()`. Reason I asked for the code was to make sure there wasn't something crazy going on. You never know!

Comment: I added a minimal reproducible example. What's very odd is that `allTypes.Contains(typeof(ZipCodeRepository<ZipCode>))` returns `false`, even though the type is clearly contained in the array. `allTypes[5] = typeof(ZipCodeRepository<ZipCode>)` also returns `false`. Strange stuff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255691/discussion-between-intexx-and-travis-illig).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is some confusion here over open generics vs. closed generics. First, let me post a slightly updated version of your repro that uses unit testing:

```cs
public class UnitTest1
{
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : Entity
    {
    }

    public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity
    {
    }

    public abstract class Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IZipCodeRepository<T> : IRepository<ZipCode> where T : ZipCode
    {
    }

    public class ZipCodeRepository<T> : Repository<ZipCode>, IZipCodeRepository<ZipCode> where T : ZipCode
    {
    }

    public class ZipCode : Entity
    {
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Succeeds()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<ZipCodeRepository<ZipCode>>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
        var container = builder.Build();
        container.Resolve<IZipCodeRepository<ZipCode>>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Fails()
    {
        var baseType = typeof(Repository<Entity>);
        var allTypes = baseType.Assembly.GetTypes().ToArray();
        Assert.Contains(typeof(ZipCodeRepository<ZipCode>), allTypes);

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterTypes(allTypes).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        var container = builder.Build();
        container.Resolve<IZipCodeRepository<ZipCode>>();
    }
}
```

The problem with this repro is that the `Fails` unit test actually fails BEFORE the resolve call - it fails here:

```cs
// This fails
Assert.Contains(typeof(ZipCodeRepository<ZipCode>), allTypes);
```

The reason is that what you have declared is an *open generic*. It's `ZipCodeRepository<T>` where `T` is not filled in.

```cs
// This passes - the open generic IS there.
Assert.Contains(typeof(ZipCodeRepository<>), allTypes);
```

This is important because `RegisterAssemblyTypes` *does not register open generics*. There's a different registration for open generic (`builder.RegisterGeneric` - [docs here](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components)) and for handling assembly scanning with open generics ([docs here](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html)).

If we update the failing unit test for a moment just to register the one type in question (let's skip assembly scanning for a second), we have:

```cs
[Fact]
public void Fails()
{
    var baseType = typeof(Repository<Entity>);
    var allTypes = baseType.Assembly.GetTypes().ToArray();
    Assert.Contains(typeof(ZipCodeRepository<>), allTypes);

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ZipCodeRepository<>)).AsImplementedInterfaces();
    var container = builder.Build();
    container.Resolve<IZipCodeRepository<ZipCode>>();
}
```

So far so good, but now we get a resolution exception:

> The service 'IRepository`1[[ZipCode, TestRepro, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' is not an open generic type definition.

That is, `IRepository<ZipCode>` is not a generic type definition. Let's look at the class and interface:

```cs
public interface IZipCodeRepository<T> : IRepository<ZipCode> where T : ZipCode
{
}

public class ZipCodeRepository<T> : Repository<ZipCode>, IZipCodeRepository<ZipCode> where T : ZipCode
{
}
```

Hmmm, the `<ZipCode>` part of most of those things seem like typos. We want the type parameter to be generic with a constraint, not filled in. Let's fix that:

```cs
public interface IZipCodeRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : ZipCode
{
}

public class ZipCodeRepository<T> : Repository<T>, IZipCodeRepository<T> where T : ZipCode
{
}
```

**Now when we run the test, it passes.** So the problem there was incorrect generic declarations.

Let's try updating the test now with assembly scanning:

```cs
[Fact]
public void DoesNotFailAnymore()
{
    var baseType = typeof(Repository<Entity>);
    var allTypes = baseType.Assembly.GetTypes().ToArray();
    Assert.Contains(typeof(ZipCodeRepository<>), allTypes);

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterAssemblyOpenGenericTypes(baseType.Assembly)
        .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.Name == typeof(IRepository<>).Name))
        .AsImplementedInterfaces();
    var container = builder.Build();
    container.Resolve<IZipCodeRepository<ZipCode>>();
}
```

**That works.** Note there is some name comparison weirdness where `GetInterfaces()` on an open generic returns a type, and `type(IRepository<>)` is a type, but while the types are the same, they don't show up as *equal* in the LINQ query, so I did a shortcut and used name. You can update the filter there how you like.

So, in summary, the problems with the original code:

- Incorrect registration of open generics.
- Incorrect definition of generic types.

Comment: So I had my generics wrong and I was calling the wrong registration method. I'd say that was a little more than just a typo, Travis 